# How to update/re-render component only after last XHR completed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

I'm trying to optimize live search component and main problem is a lot of XHR requests on every input change. After every letter added - there're new request to server, and requests taking different time to complete. So, the latest completed XHR (actually, it is first XHR, because it often returns all data) emits rendering the component.
How can I update component only on last called XHR complete?

**Example in image:**
I need to update component only on 2 XHR complete, but now it updates on each XHR completing and the last data in component is from 1 XHR, because it takes more time to complete.

[image]

There is my `componentDidUpdate` method:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (!isEqual(this.props.userFilterData, prevProps.userFilterData)) {
        const {
            userFilterData,
            initPagination
        } = this.props;
        user
            .find(userFilterData)
            .then(() => initPagination(user.selectors.find(userFilterData)));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of firing search request on every input change. You should [debounce](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/debounce-in-javascript-improve-your-applications-performance-5b01855e086) the event so the XHR is fired only once pex X ms (300-400ms). To ensure that only last XHR request is rendered you should cancel those fired before.

If you are using axios you can [cancel](https://github.com/axios/axios#cancellation) request per docs. Other libs may have different methods

Comment: Thanks, I created a debounced function and now send only one response after changing, but now, React don’t update component on response. How can I update component? By setState?

Comment: Yes in your XHR request after you recieve data you need to update state to trigger re-render  using `setState`